# Griddle pan vs. Large frypan?

Tags: cookware

I used to have a Lodge cast iron griddle that fit over 2 burners but the middle wouldn't get hot properly so I put it in the closet.

Instead I bought 2 separate stainless steel demeyere brand griddles with a shallow lip around it:
https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/31QS7WXC5QL.jpg

The more I think about it, is there anything that these stainless griddles could do that I can't do with a 12-13 inch frypan.

I'm considering buying 2 frypans instead.

Can someone help me please?

Comment: A frying pan can also be used to make a pan sauce or otherwise reduce liquid, which may be difficult in a griddle with a very small lip like the one you linked.

Comment: Is this question about the merits of cast iron vs stainless or about the differences between a single unit griddle pan and a stainless steel frying pan

Comment: Lodge also makes a [round, smooth griddle with a slight lip](https://www.amazon.com/Lodge-Pre-Seasoned-Cast-Iron-Griddle-10-5-inch/dp/B00008GKDN).  I love it because it heats up faster than a pan and heats more evenly (not as much of a drop in temperature near the side walls), an it's easier to make full use of it as you can more easily get a spatula in there to flip things.

Comment: It's about the single unit griddle with small lip vs. getting a frypan.  The Lodge cast iron was put in as backstory for my progression in cookware.

Comment: Did your stove come with a gas ring you can put on the largest burner?

Answer (score 1):

Handling flatbreads, pancakes, crepes, patties.... and other flatfood will  be more awkward with a deeper pan, you will need to lift (and probably damage) the food more to get a tool underneath it.

Evaporation can be quicker with a very shallow or completely flat pan or griddle, due to less possibility of steam gathering up in the pan itself (compare to the pathological case of sauteing in a stockpot). But the pans you bought are already very shallow.

The visual impression of the actual cooking will be far more mundane if frypans are used (if that didn't matter in cooking, Teppanyaki would never ever have been invented).

Also, cooking a 14+ inch long piece of food whole will be difficult.

Comment: What if I the frypan had the same amount of cooking surface as the griddle? Then which is better?

Comment: Same amount of horizontal cooking surface or total inner surface?